# Android Studio could not detect Redmi 5A

Tags: android, android-studio, redmi-device

I connected my Redmi 5A using a USB cable, with developer and USB debugging enabled, but somehow android studio could not detect my device when I click the run icon.

[image: could not detect my device]

I tried to troubleshoot the issue and the event log showed this:

[image: log error]

What is the issue here?

Comment: have you installed USB driver of your mobile in your system ?

Comment: @KarthicSrinivasan i tried looking from the official website but couldn't find it, some other websites do provide but im not sure if it is legit

Comment: @samson sometimes you have to login mi account in settings by creating an id with mi , inorder to activate debugging in Redmi handsets. In Mi 4A I created mi account , after which I was allowed to run debugging mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install USB Drivers for your device. Some devices don't work without driver ( like Samsung )

[Download here](https://c.mi.com/thread-1625831-1-1.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you connect the Device, Android Studio shows a notification on the remote device (here Redmi 5A). If you select **Allow Debugging From this computer: `COMPUTER KEY`**, Android Studio will show the device in the list. If not selected, you have to disable USB Debugging and start it again and this is the main problem here in your question (as said in the log)!

Also see that you use USB for transferring files!

Also if you have done this correctly, try staring the adb sever again. Open the terminal window by clicking **Terminal** on the bottom of Android Studio.

Then type:

```
adb kill-server
```

Then type:

```
adb start-server
```

Comment: i tried the above commands, does not work for me, the terminal will show  

'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Samson Yap Also see that you use USB for transferring files!!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Redmi 5A for testing purpose. I have faced this problem several time.I just unplugged the usb cables, turn off developer options. Then turn on the developer options again, connect with the USB. Surprisingly it works for me.